# Questions about GUID's: Are they always fixed in length, and is the middle number always 4?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I just generated a few million GUID's turned them into a String and got the length... it was always the same.  Can I rely on this fixed length of the GUID when converting to String?

Also, is the middle number of the GUID always "4" as shown in this screenshot?

[image]

Comment: You can only rely on what the spec says about the GUID.  If the spec doesn't mention a fixed-length string representation, then don't rely on it.

Comment: @Keith - The 8-4-4-4-12 format is the standard, both with MS and the OSF. MS docs say of Guid.ToString() "The value of this Guid, formatted as follows:
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the length is fixed and yes, the middle number is always 4 when you use the standard tostring format. 
Some of the bits in GUID (known as a UUID almost anywhere that isn't windows) are fixed to indicate things like version etc..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid

**EDIT**
I should add that the "4" only applies to Guids that have been generated according to the Guid.NewGuid algorithm as implemented in .NET. There is nothing to stop you from taking any arbitrary byte[16] and converting it to Guid. So, you can only bank on it being 4 for the current implementation of the algorithm in .Net. If you are getting Guids from another source, you can't bank on the 4. An update to .Net or possibly windows(depending if .Net uses its own or Windows' generator) may change the fixed numbers of the GUID

e.g. the following is completely working code and will not have the 4 in position:

```
        var rand = new Random();
        var byteArray = new byte[16];
        rand.NextBytes(byteArray);
        var g = new Guid(byteArray);
```

Comment: The 4 is the version number. It depends on how it was generated, *not* how you convert it to a string.

Comment: If you displayed the GUID as a base-10 number, there wouldn't be a 4 in that position always. Mind you, doing that would be insane, it's just that you COULD.

Comment: @Gabe - to shorten the string length, a semi- common trick is to do a base 64 conversion, in which case the string would not have the 4 in position, it would mask the fixed values. eg: Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());

Comment: @Jim Leonardo - Will the Base64 GUID always have the same length?

Comment: MakerOfThings7: a GUID is by definition 128 bits. Any reasonable algorithm for converting one to a string will always generate strings of the same length.

Comment: @Maker - A GUID is always 16 bytes, the byte array is therefore byte[16], so I don't see how the length ToBase64String would ever change for the Guid.ToByteArray.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation on Guid.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx) (with no parameters):

> The value of this Guid, formatted as
>   follows: 
>   xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
>   where the value of the GUID is
>   represented as a series of lowercase
>   hexadecimal digits in groups of 8, 4,
>   4, 4, and 12 digits and separated by
>   hyphens. An example of a return value
>   is
>   "382c74c3-721d-4f34-80e5-57657b6cbc27".

So the answer is "yes", it will *always* be the same length.

As for the 4, it is a version number (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid). Every GUID that you generate with that algorithm will have a 4 in that position, but older GUIDs will have a 1, 2, or 3. Future ones might have a 5 or something higher.

Answer (score 3):

No - a GUID does not have to be a type 4 UUID in fact many GUIDS under windows are UUID's of TYPE 1.

Type 1 takes the primary MAC, a clock and a sequence. This in fact "Leaks" data since all the UUID1s that are created on the same system will have the same MAC. That is why most GUID functions will take this data and hash it and turn it into a hash-based UUID